# Visiblox/WPF can't zoom with series on additional Y axis

Tags: wpf, zooming, visiblox

I have a Visiblox chart with multiple Y-axes, different units on each axis.

The user can click any of several buttons to display data as line series on the appropriate axis.

If the user clicks on data that plots against the primary or secondary Y-axis, it's possible to zoom the plot.  If they click on data that plots on an "additional" Y-axis and there is no existing data on the primary or secondary Y-axis, the plot will not zoom.

If there is existing data plotted against the primary or secondary Y-axis, the chart zooms fine.

I'm guessing this is expected behavior in Visiblox, but am I missing any way to enable zooming with data plotted only on an "additional" Y-axis?

I know I could keep track of which axes are active and change the units on them to make sure that data is always plotted first on one of the functioning axes, but the user can also remove data from any axis at will, and I'd have to replot the data any time they removed data from the both of the functioning axes, leaving only data on the "additional" axis.  Possible, but messy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From correspondance on the Visiblox blog, this is a known issue that will be addressed in the upcoming 2.2 release of Visiblox.  Thanks to the Visiblox team for responding there!

http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2010/11/zooming-panning-in-silverlight-using-visiblox-charts